# Access a maven resource jar from java code

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jar, mojo

I am creating a maven plugin and need to retrieve a jar from within my code. I don't want to just search through the .m2 folder, but actualy use maven to retrieve the requested resource (both local and remote resources). How can I do this?

PS, once the jar file is available, I already have code to read the jar, so I don't need help with that.

Comment: Please explain your use case best with a real project example...and I doubt that you need to implement a maven-plugin ...in your own code? (Why?)

Comment: @khmarbaise actually, I am creating a maven plugin. I am not happy with the way that the maven template plugin works, so I am trying to write my own.

Comment: Which template plugin ? And what do you don't like ?

Comment: @khmarbaise the maven-template-plugin is what I believe it is called. What I don't like about it is its use of Velocity and the inconsistency in what methods can be called. I also dislike that it is so unfrequently used that I can't find anyone that is able to help me with the problems I am facing with the plugin, even to the extent that the documentation is outdated and not helpful in trying to solve those problems.